# How do I create a plot with 6 line subplots in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I have 6 different data frames and I would like to make 1 figure displaying 6 graphs with year on the x axis and incident cases per 100k on the y axis for each.  I have been using the following code to create a single graph that I desire, but now I am stuck on how to get them all into 1 figure.

```
px.line(gyeEUR, x="year", y="incident cases per 100k", color="country", title="Incident Cases per 100k in Europe")
```

I simply want this plot 6 times using 6 different data frames (ie gyeEUR, gyeEMR ....).  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Depending on how the countries are sorted within the dataframe you might have problems with colors and legends.

Comment: I updated my answer do you mind to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider to read all 6 dataframes, add a column to them  `df_i["fn"]= "filename"`
and finally concat them to a bigger dataframe `df` and use

```py
px.line(df,
        x="year",
        y="incident cases per 100k",
        color="country",
        title="Incident Cases per 100k in Europe",
        facet_row="fn")
```

**Update: full example**

## Generate data

Here we simply read the data for gapminder builted-in `plotly.express` and split in several files for continent. Given that the continent is in the file name we drop that column inside every group

```py
import os
import plotly.express as px
os.makedirs("data", exist_ok=True)

df = px.data.gapminder()

df.groupby("continent")\
  .apply(lambda x: 
         x.drop("continent", axis=1)\
          .to_csv("data/{}.csv".format(x.name),
                  index=False))
```

## Read data and concat

```py
# list all csv in data/
files = os.listdir("data/")
files = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.csv'), files))

# read, add continent and concat

out = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f"data/{file}")
    df["continent"] = file[:-4]
    out.append(df)
df = pd.concat(out)
```

## Plot

This doesn't look that good but it's just an example

```py
px.line(df,
        x="year",
        y="pop",
        color="country",
        facet_row="continent")
```

Comment: I would still like to have plots separated out by data frame as they contain only countries from specific regions.  For example, gyeEUR contains all the data from Europe.  I have created a plot with all of the countries in one and there are just far too many lines overlapping for it to be particularly clear viewing.   Maybe, I am not fully understanding your suggestion however.

Comment: This should generate a subplot for every df. Have you tried to run it?

Comment: I am confused what you mean by adding a column ```df_i["fn"] = "filename"```.  Do I simply add that column to each of the dataframes?  Sorry very new to all of this.